# How To Hide ListView ColumnHeader?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox

I am struggling to figure out the correct control to use for a list of predefined jobs in the included form.  I currently have a ListBoxControl in the Predefined Job Name group that lists all of the predefined jobs for a marine service shop (i.e. oil change, tune up, etc...).  Then, based on the item (i.e. job name) that is selected in my ListBox, I need to display the items that correspond to that job.  For example, if oil change is the selected job I need to show 4 quarts oil, 1 oil filter, labor, etc...and so on.

Currently, when I load the form data I have a DAO that retrieves all of my jobs from the database using LINQ to SQL.  Then I iterate over the results and put the job names into the ListBox.  The problem that I am having is that there is no tag for ListBox items like there is for ListView items. So each time the user selects another item in the ListBox, I have to perform another LINQ query to get the job from the database again so that I can display its' corresponding items.  If I could use a ListView and hide the column header I could set the entire job on the tag so that each time the user selects a new item I would have access to the details without having to make another call to the database.  Is there a way that I can hide the column header of a ListView without hiding the entire column?

[image: Windows Form]

Comment: I would use a grid if tabular data should be shown, I believe in a GridView you can hide the HeaderRow.

Comment: Your `View` mode is set to `Details`. Why not set it to `List`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can set the `HeaderStyle` member of the `ListView` to `None`.

`listView1.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;`

Answer (score 9):

Checkout the ListView [HeaderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.headerstyle.aspx) property. It has the following options:

1. None
2. Nonclickable
3. Clickable

**From MSDN:**

The HeaderStyle property allows you to specify whether the column headers are visible or, if they are visible, whether they will function as clickable buttons. If the HeaderStyle property is set to ColumnHeaderStyle.None, the column headers are not displayed, although the items and subitems of the ListView control are still arranged in columns

Answer (score 1):

You can also create simple object like `ListItem` which has two poperties: `Text` (string) and `Tag` (object). Then implement ListItem.ToString() and you can use these in the `ListBox` as well.

You can also check out [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) component, which is free and allows displaying items in *Details* view without columns. The advantage over ListBox and ListView is a native look and many extra features.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you know for a fact you are not displaying the headers it may be best to set the HeaderStyle property to None, as Rajesh mentions above.

When setting in the .CS when screen initially loads the headers are displayed until screen is fully rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is using the `ColumnWidthChanging` event

```
private void listViewExtended1_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
      {
           e.Cancel = true;
           e.NewWidth = listViewExtended1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
      }
}
```